# sliderInput update animation interval dynamically

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to be able to update the sliderInput animation interval argument **while the animation is still playing.**

here is a simple working app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('slider'),
  actionButton('faster', 'faster'),
  actionButton('slower', 'slower'),
  br(),
  htmlOutput('displaySpeed')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput('slider', 'Slider', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1,
                animate = animationOptions(interval = animation$speed))
  })

  # update animation interval 
  animation <- reactiveValues(speed = 100)
  observeEvent(input$faster, {animation$speed <- animation$speed - 20})
  observeEvent(input$slower, {animation$speed <- animation$speed + 20})

  output$displaySpeed <- renderText({
    HTML("Current interval:", animation$speed)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

if I start the animation and change speed by clicking the actionButtons, the animation resets to the beginning.
If I add isolate(animation$speed) to the interval argument, the interval is not changed once the animation starts.

Is there a way to have interval change **while** the animation is playing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Shiny JavaScript event `shiny:value` for the UI object (`slider_div`) we can continue the animation by reclicking the play button automatically immediately after the re-render prompted by the change in `animate$speed` has completed.

I've changed the max to 100 and enabled loop just to demonstrate the functionality.

EDITS: Added a custom message so that if a re-render of the slider input occurs that wasn't a result of the faster/slower buttons, it is ignored (requested by OP in comments).

**www/shiny-events.js**

```
$(function() {
    var renders = 0;
    var press_play = false;
    $(document).on({

        // COULD ALSO DO $('#slider_div').on('shiny:value', function() {...})
        'shiny:value': function(event) {
            switch (event.name) {
                case 'slider_div':
                    // WONT RESUME IF THE RENDER WAS DUE TO SOMETHING ELSE
                    if (renders > 0 && press_play) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log('Animation Speed Changed!');
                            $('.slider-animate-button').click();
                        }, 200);

                        press_play = false;
                    } else {
                      renders = 1;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
            } 
        }

    });


    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('resume', function(message) {
        press_play = true;
    });
});
```

**app.R**

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(singleton(tags$script(src = 'shiny-events.js'))),

  numericInput("min", "Min", value = 0, min = 0, max = 10),
  numericInput("max", "Max", value = 100, min = 100, max = 200),
  sliderInput("speed", "Animation Speed", value = 100, ticks = FALSE, round = 50, min = 50, max = 1000),
  uiOutput('slider_div'),
  br(),
  htmlOutput('displaySpeed')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$slider_div <- renderUI({

    sliderInput(
        inputId = 'slider'
      , label   = 'Slider'
      , min     = input$min
      , max     = input$max
      , value   = isolate(animation$value)
      , animate = animationOptions(interval = animation$speed, loop = TRUE)
    )

  })

  # update animation interval 
  animation <- reactiveValues(speed = 100, value = 1)

  observeEvent(input$speed, {
    invalidateLater(500, session)

    animation$value <- input$slider
    animation$speed <- input$speed
  })

  output$displaySpeed <- renderText({
    HTML("Current interval:", animation$speed)
  })

  observeEvent(input$speed, {
    session$sendCustomMessage('resume', TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$min | input$max, {
    animation$value <- input$slider
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Ref: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html

Especially;

> Please note `shiny:recalculated` is triggered after the output value has been recalculated in R, but that does not imply the output value has been displayed on the page. Use `shiny:value` instead if you want to do something when the output value is rendered.

Run as a Gist:

```
runGist("https://gist.github.com/McClellandLegge/71472adcfe36270ec876b455beba2bdb")
```

Session:

```
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  setting  value                       
version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
system   x86_64, mingw32             
ui       RStudio (1.1.383)           
language (EN)                        
collate  English_United States.1252  
tz       America/Chicago             
date     2018-04-27                  

Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  package     * version date       source                                   
base        * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
Cairo         1.5-9   2015-09-26 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                           
compiler      3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
curl          3.1     2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
datasets    * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
devtools      1.13.2  2017-06-02 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
digest        0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
git2r         0.18.0  2017-01-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
graphics    * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
grDevices   * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
httpuv        1.3.5   2017-07-04 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                           
httr          1.3.1   2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                           
jsonlite      1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                           
magrittr    * 1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
methods     * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
mime          0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
R6            2.2.2   2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                           
Rcpp          0.12.13 2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                           
shiny       * 1.0.5   2017-08-23 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
stats       * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
tools         3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
utils       * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                                    
withr         2.0.0   2017-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                           
xtable        1.8-2   2016-02-05 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                           
yaml          2.1.16  2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
```

Comment: I have other inputs in the app which cause the app to re-render the slider with new min/max and restarts the animation. Currently, the animation automatically starts playing when this occurs. Is it possible to pause the animation when the slider re-renders like this?

Comment: @sebdalgarno sure, take a look at the edits, hopefully that does what you want.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this doesn't appear to work, even with the demo app above. Perhaps there is a minor error?

Comment: @sebdalgarno, I've provided the full test app above with inputs for min/max, which is working just fine for me...

Comment: the problem is that now when 'faster' or 'slower' button is clicked the animation pauses. Is that happening for you?

Comment: @sebdalgarno hmm, nope, its working as intended for me, except when I click as fast as I can, in which case it sometimes stops. To fix that I've updated the answer using a slider for the speed with an invalidate later...

Comment: your gist works but I just cannot recreate in my Rstudio project. file names and code are exactly as above and the .js file is in the /www directory. What version of shiny are you running?

Comment: thanks for your efforts. It turned out that I needed to source the app script rather than select and run. I managed to get it working

Comment: I tried running the gist, but I'm getting an error: `In sliderInput(): `min`, `max`, and `value` cannot be NULL, NA, or empty.`. Using Shiny v1.6.0.

Comment: @GiovanniColitti - did you ever figure it out? I'm running into the same issue. I assume some kind of update that happened since 2018...

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the `value` option of the `sliderInput` to `isolate(input$slider)` so that when the slider is redrawn, it takes the current value as starting point.

The animation is however paused when the redraw happens.
The `renderUI` could look like (you had two elements with the id `slider` so I changed the id of `uiOutput` to `slider_holder`):

```
output$slider_holder <- renderUI({
    sliderInput('slider', 'Slider',
                min = 0, max = 10,
                value = isolate(input$slider), 
                animate =
                  animationOptions(interval = animation$speed))
  })
```